# Use json response on whereIn Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have this variable called `$result = $request->data;`

when I use something like this `return $result;` I can get sample output like this

```
 ["WLP001","WLP002","WLP003"]
```

I'm trying to use these values on `whereIn` function of laravel

Code

```
public function get_compare_data( Request $request ){
    $result = $request->data;
    $data = YeastModuleModel::whereIn('part_number', [$result])->get();
    return $data;
}
```

But I'm getting `internal server error 500`

[image]

Comment: Its seems `$result` not need to be within `[]`, its array already

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel docs, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries
The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array.

$result is an array.

you should not put $result in another array.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                    ->get();
```

so you should change your code to:

```
public function get_compare_data( Request $request ){
    $result = $request->data;
    $data = YeastModuleModel::whereIn('part_number', $result)->get();
    return $data;
}
```